# Is it grammatically correct and natural to say "don't be being rude!" when someone is being rude?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct and natural to say ***don't be being rude!*** when someone is being rude? I have heard people say something like ***don't be messing with my camera!*** when someone is messing with the camera, which made me wonder whether people say ***don't be being something***. If they do, could you tell me it it's common.

Comment: It's neither. Drop **being**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`don't be messing with my camera!`  is fairly common, but would be considered poor grammar at best in British English - other dialects maybe less so.

`don't be being rude!` isn't at all common, as Ronald says, you should just drop 'being' and go with `don't be rude!`, which is by far the most common version of that phrase, or as second choice: `stop being rude!`

Comment: "Don't be messing with my camera" isn't poor grammar; what are you talking about? "Messing" functions as an adjective, and "to be" can be applied to adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatically correct. "Being" is a participle, which functions as an adjective, and "to be" can be applied to adjectives.

But I have never heard it before in my life. I've heard things like "Don't be messing with my camera,"—which is colloquial and dialectal, but again, 100% grammatical—but doubling up on the word "be" like that sounds very strange and awkward.

What I would say is "Don't be rude." In many cases, "You are ____" as opposed to "You are *being* ____" connotes that you are *naturally* ____ rather than just being that way at this moment, but the fact you're telling someone *not* to be rude implies that you think they are not an inherently rude person and that they're capable of being polite.